# (CSS) Want to make the contents in my banner enlarge when banner is hovered over

Tags: html, css

Currently only the banner is working the text inside doesn't move with it. (I have tried overflow: hidden; but isn't work.)

```css
    .banner {
        background-color: #996633;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px 5px black;
        transition: height 0.5s;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .banner:hover {
        height: 120px;
    }

    .navbar {
        position: absolute;
        right: 13px;
        top: 17px;
        font-size: 15px;
    }


    #about-page {
        position: relative;
        right: 130px;
        bottom: 43px;  /* Example of one of the tabs, the rest same as this */
    }
```

```html
<section class="banner">
  <div id="tab">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <h2 id="about-page"><a href="#">About Us</a></h2>
      </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Position settings seems confusing. absolute children are commonly inside relative parents. Also there is no rule for `tab` class.

Comment: First couple days into learning. By adding rules to the tab class will that help with my hovering issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.banner {
  background-color: #996633;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.banner:hover h2 {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    transition: transform 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<section class="banner">
    <h2>Hello World</h2>
</section>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I added `display: flex;` Here is my code running on [codepen](https://codepen.io/ayancodes/pen/ExwRBdj) and basic concepts of flexbox [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)